# Roadmap for Push Notification & C2MD using XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, push-notification, server-push

i am planning to implement a push notification into android app , i saw so many threads related to that but i am focusing on using XMPP as i have ejabber installed already.

i came across the aSmack library but i am not aware how promising and stable that library is for 
**pubusb architecture** as this model can provide push notifications.

what i want t know is

1) even the receiver who will receive the push notification has to be constantly connected with the ejabbered server ?

2) What should i do to get the advantage of C2MD as using XMPP and aSmack i dont think i will be able t
to get the benefits of C2MD

i have tried few libraries

```
1) xtify         (paid)
2) urbanairship  (paid)
3) Android Cloud to Device Messaging ( must require google account )
```

so i guess better to create your own using XMPP , can any one help me with the above questions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a push system, you do not have to be constantly connected to ejabberd. If you prefer to handle the connection / reconnection in a battery optimized way yourself, then you do not need to implement push, as ejabberd serves as a channel for push.